# How to use kong server with etcd or consul?

Tags: docker, consul, etcd, kong

I want to use kong to manage microservices or APIs, but kong can't find new micro services which built with docker. So can kong work with etcd or consul？

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for sure you can. The guys from Kong also provide this [docker-compose](https://github.com/Mashape/docker-kong/blob/master/compose/docker-compose.yml) that has the configuration using `Consul`